# date addition when difference is column data

Tags: sql, oracle, date, addition

how to add when add data is given in another column. Also the duration is months.

```
DOJ     DURATION
--------- ----------
25-MAY-11      6
06-JUN-11      3
25-MAY-11      6
18-APR-11      2
10-MAR-11      2
18-APR-11      2
10-MAR-11      2
18-APR-11      2
10-MAR-11      2
06-JUN-11      3
10-MAR-11      4
```

out put should be date plus months
error is unidentified identifier:dateadd

Comment: how to add means ?? what did you tried ??

Comment: dateadd(mm,duration,doj)

Comment: then you should mention in your question, with expected output and current output

Comment: datediff maybe? Different Column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **[ADD_MONTHS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions004.htm#SQLRF00603)**

```
 SELECT ADD_MONTHS(DOJ,DURATION) FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```